# How to bind c# gtk vte terminal to a data stream

Tags: c#, mono, gtk, vte

Using vte-sharp.dll, I have added vte to a gtk window. I want to stream data into the terminal. But How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
term.Feed ("Hello World");
```

But I had to run this after the terminal was created first!

```
while (GLib.MainContext.Iteration ());
```